# Leetcode: Zigzag Conversion - Code runs fine in local Python IDE, but fails online test

Tags: python

[ZigZag Conversion](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/)

Hey guys,
I'm trying to pass the above test on leetcode. My code runs fine locally, but when I submit it to be tested online, it fails:

```
class Solution:
# @return a string
def convert(self, s, nRows):

    rowStrings = []
    for i in range(0,nRows):
        rowStrings.append("")

    index = 0
    direction = "DOWN"
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        rowStrings[index] = rowStrings[index] + s[i]

        print index
        print s[i]

        if (direction == "DOWN"):
            index += 1
        else:
            index -= 1

        if (index == 0):
            direction = "DOWN"
        elif (index == nRows - 1):
            direction = "UP"

    return "".join(rowStrings)
```

---

```
#the main code
sol = Solution()
print sol.convert("AB", 2)
```

---

```
Runtime Error Message:  Line 12: IndexError: list index out of range
Last executed input:    "AB", 1
```

I'm inclined to think there is a logic error somewhere, because I used the same logic in both C++ and now currently Python, and I got a runtime error according to the website. The funny thing is that locally, the answer comes out to be correct in both my C++ and Python Code, and no run-time error occurs. The python error code was more descriptive, so that's why I have posted the python code here.

Anyone else experience this / did I miss something simple here?

Comment: Please don't spam tags. There is no C++ code here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I removed it. Will keep in mind for next time

Answer (score 1):

`range()` doesn't include last argument's value, so
`range(0, 1)` would generate only `[0]`.
Then in the `for` loop you've got `index` equal to 0, then 1, which is out of bounds for `rowStrings`.
And, as you see, you have values of input arguments equal to 'AB' and 1.

Comment: Ah, I see. My code does not handle the nRows = 1 case.
Wow, this was a subtle error. How would you rewrite the code to avoid this kind of issue? Yikes.

Comment: Rather, is there something wrong with my loop style? Is my code poorly spanning the loop? Is it a "problem" that the unit of work finishes part way through the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import cycle

def convert(text, num_rows):
    # zigzag:     [0 .. num_rows-1]        [num_rows-2 .. 1]
    offsets = list(range(num_rows)) + list(range(num_rows - 2, 0, -1))

    rows = [[] for _ in range(num_rows)]
    for row, ch in zip(cycle(offsets), text):
        rows[row].append(ch)

    rows = ["".join(row) for row in rows]
    return "".join(rows)
```